# Print/log state of a variable across the runtime of the program in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

So I have a *long* piece of PHP code, which modifies a global array using loops/if statements.

Is there any direct way to print the value of the array on *every* change made to it? Perhaps using XDebug?

I'd prefer a textual log instead of doing line by line debugging using XDebug.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way of doing it via outputting JS: 
Install Firebug and then you can use `console.log(...)` and `console.debug(...)`, etc. ([see the documentation](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Message_types)).

Comment: How exactly would this help him in PHP?

Comment: hign level:  `console.log(<?php echo $value ?>);`

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug supports function traces, which dump every function call to a file on disk (see http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace). Since a recent version, the function traces can also be configured to show changes to variables as well. You can turn that on with the xdebug.collect_assignment setting (See: http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace#collect_assignments).

Answer (score 0):

Without xdebug, you may have to define a custom object (implementing `ArrayAccess`) instead of the array, and log on `offsetSet`, quick mocked up start:

```
   class ArrayLogger implements ArrayAccess {
       protected $array;
       public function __construct(array $array){
           $this->array = $array;
       }
       public function offsetGet($idx){
           return $this->array[$idx];
       }
       public function offsetExists($offset) {
           return isset($this->array[$offset]);
       }
       public function offsetUnset($offset) {
           unset($this->array[$offset]);
       }
       public function offsetSet($offset,$value){
           //do some logging here
           debug_print_backtrace();
           var_dump($this->array,$offset,$value)
           //and actually, you may need to inspect $value for arrays. & convert them all to ArrayLogger's before setting this:
           $this->array[$offset] = $value;
       }
   }
```